# How to hide a button if the cart total is less than a specific amount in woocommerce cart page dynamically

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I want to hide a button in the cart page, if the cart total is less than $500,and display if it is more than $500.

Which must be get dynamically,when i update woocommerce cart.

Checked with many ajax codes,nothing works at all.
my code:

This button i want get hide/display with cart conditions:

```
 <button id="add_cart_button_style_rg_id" onclick="onclick_pay_button()" class="add_cart_button_style_rg"></button>'


    //refresh cart page

   add_filter('add_to_cart_custom_fragments', 
     'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_custom_fragment');
        function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_custom_fragment( $cart_fragments ) {
             global $woocommerce;
             ob_start();
             ?>
            <button id="add_cart_button_style_rogue_id" class="add_to_cart_button_link" onclick="onclick_pay_button()" class="add_cart_button_style_rg"></button>
             <?php
             $cart_fragments['.add_to_cart_button_link'] = ob_get_clean();
             return $cart_fragments;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide button based on cart update, you can use JQuery.
Try following code. It uses updated_cart_totals trigger and compare the price value then hide the element

```js
jQuery (document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
<!-- get subtotal after cart updated -->
var total = jQuery('table.shop_table .cart-subtotal').html();
<!-- format the price to integer value -->
total = total.replace(/,/g, ''); // Replace comas by points
var total_val = parseInt(total);
   
if (total_val < 500) {
    jQuery("#add_cart_button_style_rogue_id").hide();
}else {
    jQuery("#add_cart_button_style_rogue_id").show();
};

});
```